# VBA Autofilter excluding blank and some of the non-blank values

Tags: excel, vba

In a column, I would have values that could be "A", "B", "C".. and also  and "NULL" values
I need to exclude the rows that are having this particular column value as either `<Blank>` or `"NULL"` or `"B"`.

I tried using Array option, but it applies filter to exclude blank valued rows.

THis is the code I've written:

```
sSource.Range("A:AG").AutoFilter Field:=13, Criteria1:="<>NULL" 'This works but gets overwritten by next line
sSource.Range("A:AG").AutoFilter Field:=13, Criteria1:="<>"
```

I have also tried using Array

```
Dim arr As Variant
arr = Array("<>NULL", "<>","<>B")
sSource.Range("A:AG").AutoFilter Field:=13, Criteria1:=arr
```